# Remove duplicate elements in python

Tags: python

for a given list for example:

```
[
    'A',
    [
        'B',
        ['D','C'],
        ['C','D']
    ],
    ['C','D'],
    ['E','F'],
    ['F','E'],
    [
        ['not','M'],
        'N',
        ['not','M']
    ]
]
```

I want to remove the duplicate element in it, the result of the above list should be:

```
[
    'A',
    [
        'B',
        ['C','D']
    ],
    ['C','D'],
    ['E','F'],
    [
        ['not','M'],
        'N'
    ]
]
```

It has two rules: `['not','A']` represents ~A, and it can be seen as one element.
If the value is same but order not, we consider it the same.So `['C','D']` is same as `['D','C']`
Can anyone one help me write this function in python to realize the requirement?

Comment: SO is no a code writing service. You supply the code and the other users will assist you in solving problems with it.

Comment: You should be able to convert every `list` to a `set` to get the required end result. Just recurse through your data. Note that this DOES remove ordering.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I agree with Klaus D.'s comment.  But I thought the question was interesting since the easiest way I could think of was using lists->tuples->sets and that gets kind of interesting when you want to remove elements.  It also causes you to lose the ordering of the original input list (As noted by Adam Smith).

So given all that, consider:

```
import itertools

def _reduce(lst):
    if not isinstance(lst, list): return lst

    seen = []
    for x in lst:
        if not any(list(perm) in seen for perm in itertools.permutations(x)):
            seen.append(_reduce(x))
    return seen
```

Which you can run by:

```
lst = [
    'A',
    [
        'B',
        ['D','C'],
        ['C','D']
    ],
    ['C','D'],
    ['E','F'],
    ['F','E'],
    [
        ['not','M'],
        'N',
        ['not','M']
    ]
]
print _reduce(lst)
```

Which outputs:

```
[
    'A', 
    [
        'B', 
        ['D', 'C']
    ], 
    ['C', 'D'], 
    ['E', 'F'], 
    [
        ['not', 'M'], 
        'N'
    ]
]
```

Note that this preserves input ordering of list elements.  Also note, that because of this, this output differs slightly from your expected output (`['D', 'C']` is preserved and `['C', 'D']` is discarded).

---

**Edit** Per your commment, `itertools.permutations()` won't suffice, since you seem to want some recursive function that will consider the permutations of the subelements as well.  What about:

```
import itertools

def _permutations(x):
    if not isinstance(x, list): return x

    perms = []
    for prod in itertools.product(*[_permutations(elem) for elem in x]):
        for perm in itertools.permutations(prod):
            perms.append(list(perm))

    return perms

def _reduce(lst):
    if not isinstance(lst, list): return lst

    seen = []
    for x in lst:
        if not any(list(perm) in seen for perm in _permutations(x)):
            seen.append(_reduce(x))
    return seen

def lexsort(x): return sorted(str(e) for e in _permutations(x))

arrs =  [
    ['B',['C','D']],
    [['D','C'],'B'],
]

print _reduce(arrs)
```

Outputs:

```
[['B', ['C', 'D']]]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you code. It works really well in some normal conditions. But consider this case: [['B',['C','D']],[['D','C'],'B']], it still returns [['B',['C','D']],[['D','C'],'B']]. But actually these two elements are the same. How to solve this kind of case?